# Sorting two non-identical vectors identically

Tags: r, string, vector, syntax

I have a vector which looks as follows:

```
avector <- c("outcome", "city", "year", "as.factor(educ)", "age", "log(area)", "peopleinhouse")
```

I have second vector which looks like this:

```
svector <- c("outcome", "educ", "city", "year", "age", "peopleinhouse", "area")
```

I am looking for a piece of code that automates getting them in the same order. Which order that is is not important.

EDIT: Please note that the solution should keep the vectors intact, with the exception of the order of course.

Obviously simple sorting won't work. I have considered something like:

```
test <- as.formula(paste(avector[1], paste(avector, collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ "))
all.vars(test)
sort(test)
```

And then to apply the same sorting to the old vector by index. But I go don't know how to go about this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach is good to create a formula object and use `all.vars` . You can use `match` and `order` to get them in same order as `svector`.

```
test <- as.formula(paste(avector[1],paste(avector,collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ "))
tmp <- all.vars(test)
avector[order(match(tmp, svector))]

#[1] "outcome" "as.factor(educ)" "city" "year" "age" "peopleinhouse" "log(area)"
```

If all value of `svector` will be present in `avector`, we can use only `match` :

```
avector[match(svector, tmp)]
```

---

Another way to get `tmp` is by regex and use the same `match` procedure as above.

```
tmp <- gsub('.*\\(|\\)', '', avector)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I might have failed at explaining what I want properly (I will make the edit). Or there is a typo in your answer. In any way, the idea is two keep the two vectors as they are (or restore them to how they are), with the exception of the order.

Comment: You need to change the last part while subsetting. See updated answer.